Working of Siphon in Vacuum
I have just studied about working principle of a siphon, I read that atmospheric pressure is one of the main agent in its working principle, but I was amazed to know that it could also work in vacuum and I found that cohesive forces between the fluid molecules is the reason behind it.
My Questions:

How can cohesive forces alone contribute to move the liquid in the siphon?
Can "Flying Drop Siphon" work in vacuum? If yes, How?


Do you know of a video showing a siphon working in a vacuum?

Use the PSE site search bar $\uparrow$. Related questions here, here and possible duplicate here.

@DavidWhite -- I just have read about it.
